# How can I rotate AND flip horizontally a video in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I am using these commands but it doesn't seem to respect the one that flips. It only rotates the media, but doesn't flip.
How can I rotate to four directions (0, 90, 180 and 270) and mirror horizontally the video?

[image]

Comment: If you provide 2 `-filter:v` options, FFmpeg takes only the last one. If you want to run another filter on the output of a filter, you create a filter chain with filters separated by commas. So, `rotation,hflip` does rotation then flip. add all your rotation options before the comma.

Answer (score 1):

As @kesh makes clear, multiple filters require either a `filter chain` or a `-filter_complex`.

The following examples are in no way perfect but work on my box, so aim for something similar.

A filter chain:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "drawtext=text='Stack Overflow': fontcolor=white: fontsize=60: x=(w-text_w)/2: y=(h-text_h)/2, rotate=90*PI/180 , hflip "  -c:a copy  -preset ultrafast -f matroska - | ffplay -autoexit -
```

A filter_complex:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "drawtext=text='Stack Overflow': fontcolor=white: fontsize=60: x=(w-text_w)/2: y=(h-text_h)/2 [v0];[v0] rotate=90*PI/180 [v1];[v1] hflip [vid]" -map "[vid]" -map 0:a -preset ultrafast -f matroska - | ffplay -autoexit -
```

Both have text added to demonstrate the horizontal flip, both are piped into ffplay for ease of demonstration and both result in the following:

[image]